# Is it Possible to Connect Arduino through the EthernetShield to Read a Text File?

Tags: javascript, arduino, file-writing

I'm new to Arduino and am trying to connect it to the internet using an EthernetShield. Before I buy the EthernetShield, I want to make sure I will be able to execute the necessary steps with it. Is it possible to use Javascript to write to a text file stored on the server (containing binary data), connect to said server/file address with Arduino, and then use Text Finder (Arduino's) to read the file's binary data and perform the necessary commands? If so, what are the steps (if it diverges from this basic outline)?

It seems fairly straight forward, but through my own research, I am unsure if text files can be written and stored in that fashion, and if the Arduino can read this file type. I'm also aware that the conventional way entails PHP and mySQL, both of which I am fairly unfamiliar with.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to read the file and parse it on the Arduino. One thing to bare in mind is the file size though. The Arduino Uno (most common these days) doesn't have a lot of memory, I'd rather use multiple smaller files (with part of the commands) rather than a massive file with everything in one go, just to avoid the risk of running out of memory.

Comment: Alright thanks! I'm using an ArduinoMega, would it be easier to set it up as a server and send binary directly to it through the website? Is that possible?

Comment: You might want to check out [Firmata](https://github.com/firmata/arduino). I think there was a discussion a while back about enabling this via the EthernetSheild. I haven't tried it myself, but might worth a look.

Comment: Great, thanks so much!

Comment: No worries, please post the results back after you test as it may help people in the future running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino can read text file. I suggest you use XMl or json instead of text file.

I am sharing a link of code for my final year btech project "Controlling devices using internet". 
(ofcourse this can be done easily by using arduino+ethernet as server but the problem with this is you need port forward the router in order to access server from outside the local network Port forwarding is little risk as per security aspects.)

I used apache server (for testing I installed in my laptop, later I used hosting sites) and Arduino+Ethernet Shield as client. Arduino sends HTTP request to server for XML file after getting, it parses the XMl and control the devices. I used PHP for creating UI and updating XML file.... 
I hope this may be useful

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxWdBbr_6RYkSXVwcGxOa3pxTDA&usp=sharing